# C# - непонятно, как работает подсчет количества элементов коллекции с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

```
List<object> li = new List<object>() {0,1,"текст 1",0,2,3,3.4,4,3,1,9,3.4,"1"};

foreach (var x in li.GroupBy(c => new { Name = c }).
  Select( c => new { c.Key.Name, Count = c.Count() }))
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name} содержится: {x.Count}  {x.Name.GetType()}");
}
```

Здесь с помощью лямда выражений происходит поиск количества элементов в списке. Но я не понимаю как это работает.

Comment: Читайте что делает метод [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx), затем читайте, что делает метод [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) и все станет понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак у вас есть коллекция объектов.

`GroupBy` в `foreach` формирует структуру `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` в TKey в данном случае записывается экземпляр анонимного типа с единственным полем Name а во внутреннюю коллекцию частичного результата группировки `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>.elements` все копии объекта переданного в Name с типом TElement. В данном тип `TElement` это `object`.

Структура `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` чем-то напоминает `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, List<TElement>>>`, где TKey общий признак для группировки, а List все элементы удовлетворяющие признаку.

Затем вы делаете Select по этой структуре в которой пробегаете по всем `KeyValuePair<TKey, List<TElement>>` и создаете коллекцию экземпляров других анонимных типов которые содержат поля Name и Count в которые вы записываете сответственно `(TKey).Name` экземпляра первого анонимного типа и количество объектов в коллекции `(List<TElement>).Count`.

Затем эта коллекция анонимных экземпляров попадает в `foreach` в которой вы поочередно выводите `.Name` и `.Count`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что помогли разобраться. Все понял.

Comment: @Dellit, ответ-то примите (галочка под кнопками для голосования слева)